# Convert list of tuples to dataframe - where first element of tuple is column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples in the format:

```
tuples = [('a',1,10,15),('b',11,0,3),('c',7,19,2)]  # etc.
```

I wish to store the data in a `DataFrame` with the format:

```
      a       b     c      ...  

0     1       11     7     ...   
1     10      0      19    ...  
2     15      3      2     ...
```

Where the first element of the tuple is what I wish to be the column name.

I understand that if I can achieve what I want by running:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tuples)
df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

But it seems to me like it should be more straightforward than this. Is this a more pythonic way of solving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [151]: pd.DataFrame({x[0]:x[1:] for x in tuples})
Out[151]:
    a   b   c
0   1  11   7
1  10   0  19
2  15   3   2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dictionary comprehension, like:

```
pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,*v in tuples})
```

in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), or:

```
pd.DataFrame({t[0]: t[1:] for t in tuples})
```

in [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

which generates:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,*v in tuples})
    a   b   c
0   1  11   7
1  10   0  19
2  15   3   2
```

The columns will be sorted *alphabetically*.

If you want the **columns to be sorted like the original content**, you can use the `columns` parameter:

```
pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,*v in tuples},columns=[k for k,*_ in tuples])
```

again in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), or for [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7):

```
pd.DataFrame({t[0]: t[1:] for t in tuples},columns=[t[0] for t in tuples])
```

We can shorten this a bit into:

```
from operator import itemgetter

pd.DataFrame({t[0]: t[1:] for t in tuples},columns=map(itemgetter(0),tuples))
```

Comment: I am currently running python 2.7, so am I correct in thinking starred expressions wont work? Otherwise looks like a good solution!

Comment: @tfcoe: that's correct. Then you better use slice notation. Will update it.

Comment: Good note on the sorting too. Luckily my data is both previously sorted alphabetically and the desired output is also in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if the values in tuple are in row wise, then

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=tuples[0])[1:]
```